# Averaging vectors with weights

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a vectors table:

the size of the vectors is 300
I need to average the vectors by multiple every vector by weight,
But there is a 300 columns, so i need to multiply every 300 columns with scalar
So, maybe i need to store the vectors as array.

What is the most elegant syntax for this query?

Dummy example but the dimension is 3:

```
with users as ( 
  select 123 user_id, '1.123' article_id UNION ALL 
  SELECT 123 user_id, '1.1234' article_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 user_id, '1.1234' article_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 user_id, '1.12345' article_id 
  ),
VECTORS AS (
  SELECT '1.123' article_id, 1 _0_, 1 _1_, 1 _2_ UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.1234' article_id, 2 _0_, 2 _1_, 2 _2_ UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.12345' article_id, 3 _0_, 3 _1_, 3 _2_ 
  ),
VFIVF AS (
  SELECT '1.123' article_id, 0.5 vf UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.1234' article_id, 0.4 vf UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.12345' article_id, 0.9 vf 
  )

SELECT 
  USER_ID ,
  AVG(VF*_0_) _0_,
  AVG(VF*_1_) _1_,
  AVG(VF*_2_)_2_
FROM 
  (  
    SELECT USERS.USER_ID,VFIVF.VF, VECTORS.* FROM USERS
    JOIN VECTORS
    ON 
    VECTORS.ARTICLE_ID = USERS.ARTICLE_ID
    JOIN VFIVF
    ON
    USERS.ARTICLE_ID = VFIVF.ARTICLE_ID
  )
GROUP BY 1
```

Output:

```
USER_ID _0_  _1_   _2_
123    0.65  0.65  0.65
1234   1.75  1.75  1.75
```

Comment: show example of expected output/result

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Edited with Dummies

Comment: looks like your dummies do not represent your case. can you provide example of data with all three dimensions and expected result. I can be wrong - but I think it is mostly VFIVF  that is missing to be properly presented

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - What do you mean ? - Do not present my data

Comment: i might be wrong with this - I thought in your original question you stated that each element in vector will have its own weight. but looks like the weight is per vector - please confirm. so the query you presented is for 3 dimensions  - and you are asking for streamlined version of that query in case of 300 elements. I think i got  it right now

Comment: You are right, There is only 1 weight for article_id\Vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  user_id ,
  dimension,
  AVG(vf * v) v,
FROM (  
  SELECT u.user_id,f.vf, v.*
    , SPLIT(REPLACE(kv, '"', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)] dimension
    , CAST(SPLIT(REPLACE(kv, '"', ''), ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS FLOAT64) v
  FROM USERS u
  JOIN VECTORS v USING(article_id)
  JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(v), '{}'))) kv
  JOIN VFIVF f USING(article_id)
  WHERE SPLIT(REPLACE(kv, '"', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)] != 'article_id'
)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

when applied to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row user_id dimension   v    
1   123     _0_         0.65     
2   123     _1_         0.65     
3   123     _2_         0.65     
4   1234    _0_         1.75     
5   1234    _1_         1.75     
6   1234    _2_         1.75
```

You can either leave result as is or depends on further usage you can do many different things from here - for example you can pack those into array per user as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(dimension, v)) avg_dims
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id ,
    dimension,
    AVG(vf * v) v,
  FROM (  
    SELECT u.user_id,f.vf, v.*
      , SPLIT(REPLACE(kv, '"', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)] dimension
      , CAST(SPLIT(REPLACE(kv, '"', ''), ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS FLOAT64) v
    FROM USERS u
    JOIN VECTORS v USING(article_id)
    JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(v), '{}'))) kv
    JOIN VFIVF f USING(article_id)
    WHERE SPLIT(REPLACE(kv, '"', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)] != 'article_id'
  )
  GROUP BY 1, 2  
)
GROUP BY 1
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Is there an option to transpose array to columns?

Comment: please consider voting up the answer if it helped

Comment: yes. there are many posts here about transposing - you can search and if not found - you can post new specific question :o)